# Train() Caret - bestTune model accuracy differs from resampling accuracy

Tags: r, r-caret, resampling

I am running a KNN model using R's Caret package. I estimate the model's accuracy by using a bootstrap 1000 times and then make a histogram of the model's accuracy over each bootstrap.

The train() function when using the KNN method typically tests the accuracy at 5, 7 and 9 nearest neighbours and the results section provides the accuracy and kappa for different nearest-neighbours.

in my trainControl method I specify that the resample section of the model should only return the resamples from the best tuned model. However, the accuracy of the best tuned model in the results section is higher than the mean accuracy of the resample. Can someone explain why this is?

```
library(caret)
library(klaR)

data("iris")

set.seed(10)

train_controlIris <- trainControl(method="boot632", number=1000, returnResamp = 'final',savePredictions = 'final' )

modelIris <- train( Species~.,data=iris, method="knn",trControl=train_controlIris)

modelIris$results

#results are
# k  Accuracy     Kappa AccuracySD    KappaSD AccuracyApparent KappaApparent
# 5 0.9596929 0.9391343 0.02518187 0.03806050        0.9666667          0.95
# 7 0.9636048 0.9450297 0.02477967 0.03746918        0.9733333          0.96
# 9 0.9668314 0.9498840 0.02406576 0.03636270        0.9800000          0.97

mean(modelIris$resample$Accuracy)
#result is 0.9591676
```

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that you asked for the bootstrap 632 estimator, which is not the same as the simple average.

```r
library(caret)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(klaR)
#> Loading required package: MASS

data("iris")

set.seed(10)

train_controlIris <-
  trainControl(
    method = "boot",
    number = 1000,
    returnResamp = 'final',
    savePredictions = 'final'
  )

modelIris <-
  train(Species ~ .,
        data = iris,
        method = "knn",
        trControl = train_controlIris)

mean(modelIris$resample$Accuracy)
#> [1] 0.9589355
getTrainPerf(modelIris)
#>   TrainAccuracy TrainKappa method
#> 1     0.9589355  0.9378173    knn
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>